# Knockout JS Error: "The value for a submit binding must be a function"

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've setup a view model like this:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.voteOnItem = function (sender, e) { .. }

    .
    .
}

var model = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

In my view, I have this inside of a template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="X">
  <ul id="" data-bind="foreach:items">
 <li>
    <div style="float:left;">
           <form action='Url' method="post" data-bind="submit:$parent.voteOnItem">
      .
      .
```

I'm getting an error "The value for a submit binding must be a function" for the mapping to voteOnItem, but voteOnItem is clearly a function... any idea why the error?

Comment: I would ensure that you are in the right scope when you are doing the submit binding. The error that you are getting is what you would see when `$parent` has no `voteOnItem` property (like if you put `$parent.blah`).  An easy way to see is to just put a `<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent)"></div>` near where your binding to see the data at that level.  The other thing to verify is that you have all of your tags closed and are not using any bad self-closing tags like `<span />`

Comment: I'll try the JSON trick... thanks.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer That was it, thanks very much!  If you want, copy your answer to a post and I'm mark it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would ensure that you are in the right scope when you are doing the `submit` binding.

The error that you are getting is what you would see when `$parent` has no `voteOnItem` property (like if you put `$parent.blah`).

An easy way to see is to just put a `<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($parent)"></div>` near your binding to see the data at that level.

The other thing to verify is that you have all of your tags closed and are not using any bad self-closing tags like `<span />`.

Comment: To add, in my context, I had to use $root to go even to a higher scope.